# How to build a valid data model with indirect relationsship having 'null' values

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I am trying to evaluate time entries for a project service organisation.
I do have 3 Tables: Project, Project Task and Time-entry:

| Project | Task | Time entry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client | *Project * | *Project * |
| ... | Name | *Task * |
| ... | ... | ... |

i do have a

- 1:n relation from project --> task
- 1:n relation from task --> time-entry
- the time entry table also has a project column, however in my model (PowerBI) i cannot active the connection, as another indirect connection already exists (project --> task --> time entry).

So far so good. My problem now is, that some time entries do not have a task. So the task value there is 'null'.

[image]

When i want to sum the time-entries for a project, the entries with a 'null' in the task are missing since the relation is indirect and can't be traced from time-entry to project with the 'null' task.

What are my best options to handle this?

Activating the direct relation project --> time entry won't work, as i also need time entries per task.
I was thinking of replacing the 'null' values by an arbitrary (?) task from the project, but I am unsure how to do this.

Any advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the relationship between `Project` and `Time Entry`, but keep it inactive.  You can get project level metrics from the the `Time Entry` table by using `USERELATIONSHIP`:

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS('Time Entry'),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Time Entry'[Project], 'Project'[Project] )
)
```

Comment: You are my hero. This works very well and documents, that I am still a real nOOb in DAX/PowerBi. Learned a lot though. Thx